# Nuxt js dynamic route meta tags and open graph not working when deploy

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, metadata

I want to use mata tags and open graph for SEO purpose on nuxt js. project. It working fine both local and server with first sub route foulder like

pages > homepage > index.vue

But when i try to use it with deeper sub route, it working just for local but in deploy server meta tags is use default meta data

pages > form > _slug.vue

### _slug.vue

```html
<script>
import meta from '@assets/data/meta-tag.json'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      metaData: meta.metaDetail,
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.metaData.title,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'og:title',
          name: 'og:title',
          content: this.metaData.title,
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:url',
          name: 'og:url',
          content: this.$route.fullPath,
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:type',
          name: 'og:type',
          content: 'article',
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:description',
          name: 'og:description',
          content: this.metaData.description,
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:image',
          name: 'og:image',
          content: this.metaData.image,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

### meta-tag.json

```json
{
  "metaDetail": {
    "title": "Website Title",
    "description": "Website Description",
    "image": "/share_image/img.png"
  },
}
```

### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "www-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=dev nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@nuxt-hero-icons/outline": "^1.0.1",
    "@nuxt-hero-icons/solid": "^1.0.1",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "country-state-city": "^2.0.0",
    "is-url-external": "^1.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
    "nuxt-tailvue": "^1.0.82",
    "swiper": "^6.5.7",
    "v-click-outside": "^3.1.2",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-element-loading": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-select": "^3.11.2",
    "vue-spinner": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-toastification": "^1.7.11",
    "vue-transition-expand": "^0.1.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^6.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^1.3.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.0.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.7.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "postcss": "^8.2.8",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

Is anyone has been found this case?

Comment: What if you try `import meta from '~/assets/data/meta-tag.json'`? Does it work when you build/generate locally?

Comment: That work fine on localhost but still not appear for server build. is that possible to be SSR problem ?

Comment: What are the values of your `ssr` and `target` properties? Can you share your `package.json`?

Comment: I didn't set that. it should be default value ssr: true and target: 'server'

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`? Where is your code hosted?

Comment: Yes sure on the post

Comment: Trying adding it with syntax highlight next time. Where is your code hosted? I've done a repo: https://github.com/kissu/so-nuxt-head that is totally fine here: https://so-nuxt-head.herokuapp.com/articles/1 The only thing that I had to fix was the path, as told above `@/assets/data/meta-tag.json`.

Comment: Sorry for that im very new for posting in stackoverflow.
my code hosted on AWS EC2 with docker and github deploy. I have try to split some code like you do and simply deploy on netlity it work fine too. but in my main project server is not. So i totally have no idea why.

Comment: No issues and welcome! You can't deploy on Netlify with `target: server`, it only handles static content. I'm not sure that we can go further if it's related to the context of your app. Try to isolate it in your main project, in a super basic `.vue` new page, double check all the paths to your JSONs and maybe look for something that can get in the middle and make it buggy. Not sure how I can help more here.